# weirdly wired outlet burned

Tags: wiring, receptacle

My son smelled smoke and located it coming from the outlet behind and used by the refrigerator. When he pulled it out, he saw the one side of the receptacle had melted. He pulled everything out of the box and called me, a DIY wirer, for advice. Even after he sent me photos and a diagram, I had no idea why it was wired as it was, or why it had shorted. 2 wires entering the box are plastic insulated and the other 6 are fabric wrapped. I'm attaching photos and a diagram he made. Two fabric-wrapped black wires were attached to the outlet, he believes to the brass screws. The black plastic coated wire was in a silver push-in, and the the white wrapped was attached to a silver, where the insulation had been stripped. 
We're wondering why it is wired as it is, why it shorted, and whether all the wrapped wiring with no ground will have to be replaced. When it was inspected before being bought the inspector said it was 50-75 years old.[wires pulled out of box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSxRu.jpg)

[![wires pulled out of box
[[image: ][2]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozcyl.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36rnd.jpg)

Comment: The box is a charred mess and there's no guarantee  that the diagram's correct so why it was wired that way will be a mystery. Fabric covered wire is usually allowed to remain until a renovation takes place or something goes wrong. Something has dangerously gone wrong and all the wiring in that box should be replaced to each wire's termination point or further.  Don't re energize  that breaker. If this is beyond your skill set, get a pro.

Comment: Was the outlet half-switched by chance?

Comment: Does look just like that, @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: Hmmmm.  the fabric covered wire looks like it's part of an old knob&tube wiring system. I think a good question would be have there been any recent changes?  ....like the addition of a space heater elsewhere in the house?  Looking at the box I'm really glad the OP's house didn't burn down,  what was the over-current protection for that circuit?

Comment: threephaseeel   It wasn't half-switched.